# How to print blank lines in Gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

This may be naive: how do I print a blank line from a gnuplot script to a txt file? I mean without any spaces, just a return.

```
set print "filename" append # I print things in a loop and append them
print a
print b
print HowToPrintBlankLines?
```

Thanks,
Luca

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To print a blank line in gnuplot you can just do

```
print ""
```

Comment: Thanks. I don't know how I didn't think about it.